# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (28x28 and 784x128)

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, autoencoder

I'm trying to use an autoencoder on a MNIST dataset with added gaussian noise. I've used a DataLoader on the noisy MNIST dataset. After the added noise the model that worked for the original MNIST dataset doesn't work anymore.

```
gauss_train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_gauss, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, drop_last=DROP_LAST)
gauss_test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_gauss, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, drop_last=DROP_LAST)
# length = 150
```

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(28 * 28, 128),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(128, 64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
            nn.Linear(64, 12), 
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
            nn.Linear(12, 10))
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(10, 12),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(12, 64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(64, 128),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
            nn.Linear(128, 28 * 28), 
            nn.Tanh())

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x
```

```
def train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs):
    epoch_losses = []
    for epoch in trange(num_epochs):
        for data in gauss_train_loader:
            img = data[0].to(device) 
            #torch.size of img = [400,784] and of data[0] = [400,1,28,28]
            # We don't utilize the target data[1]
            img = img.view(img.size(0), -1)
            output = model(img)
            loss = criterion(output, img)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        loss_value = loss.item()
        epoch_losses.append(loss_value)
    return epoch_losses

# Train the autoencoder using the mnist train set
epoch_losses = train(gauss_train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, NUM_EPOCHS)
```

I can't figure out what the difference is between the original and the noisy dataset. Or how to adjust the autoencoder.

```
mnist_trainset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
mnist_testset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

def add_noise(dataset):
  noisy_data = []
  for data in dataset:
      img, _ = data[0], data[1]
      noisy_data += torch.tensor(random_noise(img, mode='gaussian', mean=0, var=0.05, clip=True))
  return noisy_data

train_gauss = add_noise(mnist_trainset)
test_gauss = add_noise(mnist_testset)
```

Comment: Please add the `Dataset` implementation class. more precisely where variables `train_gauss` and `test_gauss` are created.

Comment: The only place where you have a 28 x 28 shape is at the start of the model, so I suggest to print `img.shape`, right before `output = model(img)`. This should hopefully give you more insight into your problem.

Comment: @meti i've added the code for the ```train_gauss``` and ```test_gauss```

Comment: @aretor It seems that the input is three dimensional [400,28,28] and then after the first img [28,28] (same after second). It should be four dimensional. With the original dataset, after the first img the shape is [400,1,28,28] and the second [400,784].

Comment: I am not sure whether the problem is related to your `random_noise` function or to the dataset creation `add_noise` function. I posted an answer that addresses the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you desired is by extending the `MNIST` dataset class. I added several tiny changes to your implementation and it worked out.

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.optim import Adam
from PIL import Image
from typing import Optional

class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(28 * 28, 128),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(128, 64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
            nn.Linear(64, 12), 
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
            nn.Linear(12, 10))
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(10, 12),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(12, 64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(64, 128),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
            nn.Linear(128, 28 * 28), 
            nn.Tanh())

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x

def train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs):
    epoch_losses = []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for data in train_loader:
            img = data[0].to(device) 
            img = img.view(img.size(0), -1)
            output = model(img)
            loss = criterion(output, img)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        loss_value = loss.item()
        epoch_losses.append(loss_value)
    return epoch_losses

class your_noisy_dataset(datasets.MNIST):
  def __getitem__(self, index: int):
        img, target = self.data[index], int(self.targets[index])
        img = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), mode='L')
        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)
            img += torch.normal(0, 0.05, size=img.size())            
        if self.target_transform is not None:
            target = self.target_transform(target)
        return img, target

mnist_trainset = your_noisy_dataset(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
mnist_testset = your_noisy_dataset(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
model = Autoencoder()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.05)
device = torch.device("cpu")
epoch_losses = train(mnist_trainset, model, criterion, optimizer, 1)
```

The major difference in `__getitem__` method is that it would return an image plus noise mask instead of the image only. ([read more about `Dataset` class](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating a new dataset, you can apply your transformation online, by defining your own `RandomNoise` `transform`, as follows:

```py
class RandomNoise(object):
    def __init__(self, mode="gaussian", mean, var, clip):
        self.mode = mode
        ...

   def __call__(self, image):
       image = random_noise(image, self.mode, self.mean, self.var, self.clip)
       return torch.tensor(image)
```

Then you define:

```py
    t = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), RandomNoise(0, 0.05)])
    train_gauss = datasets.MNIST(root, train=True, download=True, transform=t)
    val_gauss = ...
```